# How to rename a bulk of files and remove extension

Tags: linux, rename

I am need to rename the below files. I only want to remove `.job-209675` from the filenames that begin with `SOA` but keeping the original filenames intact as there are other files in this directory

for example
Before: `./SOA_990377897NW0001_1557340549734.xml.job-2074645`
After: `./SOA_990377897NW0001_1557340549734.xml`

Comment: Also consider Larry Wall's rename command. Beware there is more than one command named rename (it depends on, so check which is installed).

Answer (score 2):

If a variable, `filename`, contains one of your files' name, then `${filename%.job-*}` would be the name without the bit after the last dot.

To loop over the filenames, renaming each one in turn,

```
for filename in SOA_*.job-*; do
    echo mv -i "$filename" "${filename%.job-*}"
done
```

The `echo` is there for protection. You should run the loop once and inspect the output, then remove the `echo` if you think it's correct.  The `-i` option to `mv` causes it to ask for confirmation before overwriting an existing file.

This assumes that all relevant files (and nothing else) are matched by the `SOA_*.job-*` pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I will try the above, this will require to be placed in script correct? Then ran

Comment: @Jack You could place it in a script, but it so short that you should be able to paste it into a terminal. The important bit is that the current working directory is the directory where you have the files.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for thanking me (in the now removed edit to the question). Please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers